# Tab refers to a missing document

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send an envelope that is composed of 
Template1 (1 pdf document)
Template2 (2 pdf documents, 1-regular fill-out, 2-with attach extra document tab)

If I use just template1 or template2 individually, I am able to send out the envelope. However, I can not send it both templates at the same time, I get the following error, and not sure what it means.

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<errorCode>TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT</errorCode>
<message>The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 2 which is not present.</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Account Setup",
    "emailBlurb": "Please fill out the form",
    "status": "sent",   
    "compositeTemplates": [{
           "compositeTemplateId": "compositeTemplate1",
           "serverTemplates": [

                    /* STANDARD ACCOUNT FORM */
                    {
                        "sequence": "2",
                        "templateId": "182B70AD-*"
                    },

                    /* ELECTRONIC TRANSFER FORM */
                    {
                        "sequence": "3",
                        "templateId": "B2B0BF8D-*"
                    }

                    ],

           "inlineTemplates": [{
                   "sequence": "1",
                   "recipients": {
                          "signers": [{
                                  "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                  "name": "First Last",
                                  "recipientId": "1",
                                  "roleName": "Client",
                                  "RequireIDLookup": "true",
                                  "RequireIDLookupSpecified": "true",
                                  "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
                                  "phoneAuthentication": {
                                              "recipMayProvideNumber": "false",
                                              "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                                                        "914-000-0000"
                                              ]
                                    }
                          }]
                   }
           }]
    }]
```

}

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try changing the value of **sequence** in each of your server template objects and in the inline template object as well, to indicate that the server template should be applied first (and second), and then the inline template should be applied after that:

```
           "serverTemplates": [

                    /* STANDARD ACCOUNT FORM */
                    {
                        "sequence": "1",
                        "templateId": "182B70AD-*"
                    },

                    /* ELECTRONIC TRANSFER FORM */
                    {
                        "sequence": "2",
                        "templateId": "B2B0BF8D-*"
                    }

                    ],

           "inlineTemplates": [{
                   "sequence": "3",
                   "recipients": {
                   ....
```

**------UPDATE------**

The Template XML you provided suggests that the problematic tag (the one causing the error message you're receiving) is the **SignerAttachment** tag with **TabLabel** set to "Signer Attachment 34" in the **Electronic Funds Transfer Form** template.  This tag is the only tag (in either XML file) that refers to **DocumentID** value **2** (I simply searched both XML files for **<DocumentID>2</DocumentID>**):

```
    <Tab>
        <DocumentID>2</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <XPosition>12</XPosition>
        <YPosition>104</YPosition>
        <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
        <Type>SignerAttachment</Type>
        <Name>Signer Attachment</Name>
        <TabLabel>Signer Attachment 34</TabLabel>
        <Value />
        <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
        <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
        <TemplateLocked>true</TemplateLocked>
        <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
    </Tab>
```

This is problematic for DocuSign, because the value of **DocumentID** indicates the document in which the tag resides (i.e., where the signer will see that tag during their signing session). So, DocuSign's looking to place this tag in the document that has an **ID=2** -- but, if you examine the contents of **<Documents>** within that XML file, you'll see only a single document (with **ID=1**) -- there is no second document (i.e., no document with **ID=2**):

```
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>File1.pdf</Name>
        <PDFBytes/>
        <AttachmentDescription>Please attach voided check, deposit slip or a copy of bank statement.</AttachmentDescription>
    </Document>
</Documents>
```

I'm not sure how things might have gotten to this state (i.e., why the DocumentID for the Signer Attachment tag refers to a document ID that doesn't exist).  However, doing the following might resolve the issue:

1. Edit the Electronic Funds Transfer Form Template in DocuSign -- remove/delete the Signer Attachment tag; save the Template.
2. Attempt your original scenario (send the Envelope using both templates). If it works, then this will confirm that the Signer Attachment tag was indeed the cause of your problem.
3. Edit the Electronic Funds Transfer Form Template in DocuSign -- add a new Signer Attachment tag in the same location as the original (removed) one existed; save the Template.
4. Attempt your original scenario (send the Envelope using both templates).

I suspect this will resolve your issue, but let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: Okay, then that might instead point to an issue with one of the templates that you're trying to use. To troubleshoot, I'd suggest that you try using the DocuSign web console to create/send an Envelope with the first template, then do the same with the second template.  If you get an error when creating an envelope via the web console with either template, that proves the problem is with the template itself (i.e., not with your code).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried that. Strangely both of the templates work great when are not together.

Comment: Strange.  If you can save each Template as XML (you can do this via the DocuSign web console), remove the document byte-stream from each XML file (to make the XML reasonably small), and update your question to post the XML representing each template, I can try to provide further feedback.  That error suggests that one of the tabs references an invalid/non-existent documentId -- we should be able to spot that issue in the Template XML.

Comment: Kim, I sent the XMLs to your company email, as they contain a bit to much sensitive information. Let me know if that is ok.

Comment: Please see the "UPDATE" section in my (updated) answer.

Comment: Kim, that was exactly the problem. When I saved the template into my own folder and removed the troubling Attachment Tab, the problem went away and I was able to send out the envelope. Now there is a problem that there is only one template showing up and the second is silent. Will focus on that error for now, if you have any suggestions, please share.

Comment: Glad to hear that the root cause of your issue has been identified.  Can you post a new question for the new issue?  I think I can offer feedback on that issue as well, but posting it as a new question will make the information more discoverable/helpful for others in the future. Thanks!