# DocuSign Rest API - TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT

Tags: java, upload, docusignapi

I'm getting the error below while try to create envelope based on template via DocuSign Rest API (Java). Getting the error message as specific document ID which is not present. I used to upload the document with Document ID as "1", but for one template I am getting below error.

```
Exception: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: {
  "errorCode": "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 69681238 which is not present."
}
```

Can anyone explain for the above scenario? do I need to do make any changes in my template or in my code? any additional parameter i have to pass?

Envelope Creation Code:

```
try {
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
} catch (IOException ioExcp) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + ioExcp);
    return null;
}
// add a document to the envelope
Document doc = new Document();
String base64Doc = Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes);

doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
doc.setName(fileName); 

doc.setDocumentId("1");

List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
docs.add(doc);
envDef.setTemplateId(templateId());
envDef.setDocuments(docs);

List<TemplateRole> templateRolesList = new LinkedList<TemplateRole>();
TemplateRole templateRole = new TemplateRole();

templateRole.setEmail(signerEmail);
templateRole.setName(signerName);
templateRole.setRoleName("Signer1");
templateRole.setRoutingOrder("1");
templateRolesList.add(templateRole);

TemplateRole templateRole2 = new TemplateRole();
templateRole2.setName(signerName1);
templateRole2.setRoleName("Signer2");
templateRole2.setRoutingOrder("2");
templateRole2.setEmail(signerEmail1);               
templateRolesList.add(templateRole2);

envDef.setTemplateRoles(templateRolesList);

envDef.setAllowRecipientRecursion("true");
envDef.setStatus("created");

try {
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

    EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId(), envDef);

    DocumentTemplateList documentTemplateList = new DocumentTemplateList();
    DocumentTemplate documentTemplate = new DocumentTemplate();
    documentTemplate.setTemplateId(templateId());
    documentTemplate.setDocumentId(doc.getDocumentId());
    documentTemplateList.getDocumentTemplates().add(documentTemplate);

    envelopesApi.applyTemplateToDocument(accountId,
            envelopId(), doc.getDocumentId(),
            documentTemplateList);  


} catch (com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you mentioned to get document ID from template list. I'm getting documents array as empty. Here is the response.

```
class EnvelopeTemplateResult {
    templateId: <templateId>
    name: Template 1
    shared: true
    password: 
    description: 
    lastModified: 2017-06-06T19:45:35.7670000Z
    pageCount: 15
    uri: /templates/<uri>
    folderName: Templates
    folderId: <folderId>
    folderUri: /folders/<folderUri>
    parentFolderUri: null
    owner: class UserInfo {
        userName: User Name
        email: email@email.com
        userId: userID
        userType: null
        userStatus: null
        uri: null
        errorDetails: null
    }
    documents: []
    recipients: null
    transactionId: null
    status: null
    documentsUri: null
    recipientsUri: null
    asynchronous: null
    envelopeUri: null
    emailSubject: Sign Document
    emailBlurb: Please sign this document
    envelopeId: null
    signingLocation: Online
    customFieldsUri: null
    envelopeIdStamping: null
    authoritativeCopy: false
    notification: null
    notificationUri: null
    enforceSignerVisibility: false
    enableWetSign: true
    allowMarkup: false
    allowReassign: false
    createdDateTime: null
    lastModifiedDateTime: null
    deliveredDateTime: null
    sentDateTime: null
    completedDateTime: null
    voidedDateTime: null
    voidedReason: null
    deletedDateTime: null
    declinedDateTime: null
    statusChangedDateTime: null
    documentsCombinedUri: null
    certificateUri: null
    templatesUri: null
    messageLock: null
    recipientsLock: null
    brandLock: null
    brandId: null
    useDisclosure: null
    emailSettings: null
    purgeState: null
    lockInformation: null
    is21CFRPart11: null
    isUniversalSignatureEnvelope: null
}
```

Comment: Please share your envelope creation code and document id's on your template. You can use the [listTemplateDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocuments/list/) api to retrieve the document id's on your template. Also see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36614213/1219543)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell your exact problem without seeing your envelope creation code.

Most likely you are using the wrong DocumentId during envelope creation.

Use the [listTemplateDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocuments/list/) api to retrieve the document id's on your template. Use the exact DocumentId's from the template during envelope creation.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36614213/1219543) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22052917/1219543)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the code snippet and added response from getListOfTemplates. Thanks again.

Comment: What is your templateId?

Comment: I see 1 document, 4 recipients and 12 tabs on your template. Are you trying to replace the document on your template when creating an envelope?

Comment: Yes, trying to replace with updated document and document contains all the tags are hidden.

Comment: Do you also want the Tabs from the template to remain on the envelope after the document is replaced?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue when using composite templates so figured I'd share in hopes no one has to go down this rabbit hole.

Our template was trying to add a checkbox group to the document that had a validation of "select exactly 1" and the anchor string for the checkbox fields did not exist on the document we were sending through the API. This validation seemed to cause the template to interpret these fields as required and gives this error message. Passing the documentId the API is returning in the error message fixed this issue but we do not want to keep track of documentIds and would rather just incrementally set them at runtime and use those values for document visibility. Removing the checkbox group completely and passing any documentId I wanted (explicitly not the Id the API is spitting back) fixed this issue.

We are looking into a new solution for the checkboxes, hopefully just using radio buttons instead.

I would take a close look at what fields have any type of validation on them and see if removing them one by one and then running your request you can find the culprit (this is how I found my checkbox group validation).